# Writing Log File and Opening in Notepad shows no carriage return

Tags: peoplesoft

I am writing strings to a log file in Peoplecode (Peoplesoft)

Snippets of my code is as follows:

```
&Line = Char(34) | &EMPLID | Char(34) | "," | Char(34) | &PHONE | Char(34);
&ErrorLogfile.WriteLine(&Line);
&Count = &Count + 1;
```

This will show each line of data in separate rows/ with line feeds...

I also use to send the log file through email using the notify code.

```
While &MyMAIL_SQL.fetch(&recp_role, &EMAILID)
If (All(&EMAILADD)) Then
&notifyTo.Push(&EMAILADD);
```

When i view the log file online, wordpad, word document there is line feed for each row of data. But when i open in Notepad, by opening straight the mail that had been attached with the log file, all the rows are combined as one.

I have tried using Process Scheduler in PSUNIX and PSNT.

Anyone have any idea or encounter the same problem in Peoplesoft Peoplecode?

Comment: Notepad requires Windows line terminators, which is CR+LF, not LF.

Comment: @RaymondChen Hi, yeah i can solve the problem by adding the Char(13). Because the situation now is when we migrate to production using the same code of writing log file, it works fine when open in Notepad. So i am kind of bewildered why now in development using the same code, when open in notepad the rows are combined in one line. Maybe there is any system settings in production that causing it to work?